# ordinal versus cardinal ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ordinals are ordered by the membership relation.  But we talk about the cardinality of a set, X, being greater than the cardinality of a set, Y, when there is an injection from Y into X, but not conversely.  Meanwhile, cardinals, qua Alephs, are initial ordinals, and we can write, e.g., |X|>|Y| to mean that the Aleph of X is greater than the Aleph of Y.  Of course, qua initial ordinals, the former is indeed greater than the latter by the membership ordering so long as there is an injection from Y into X but not conversely.  However, is this what we mean when we talk about one cardinal being "greater than" another?  Are we still appealing to the usual membership ordering on the ordinals?

Comment: The membership ordering on the initial ordinals agrees with the cardinal ordering defined in terms of injections.

Comment: Yes, thanks Brian -- but is the former what is strictly meant by, e.g., |X|<|Y|?

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals which are also cardinals (namely, initial ordinals), then the following are equivalent:

1. $|\alpha|<|\beta|$.
2. $\alpha\in\beta$.
3. $\alpha\subseteq\beta$ and $\alpha\neq\beta$.

So when you talk about $\aleph$ numbers there is no confusion.